# Get object and all descendant objects

Tags: c#

If I have the following list

```
List<FlatObject> objects = new List<FlatObject>();

objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 1, ParentID = 0, Name = "January", Amount = 1000 });          
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 2, ParentID = 0, Name = "February", Amount = 2000 });        
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 3, ParentID = 0, Name = "March", Amount = 3000 });    
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 4, ParentID = 0, Name = "April", Amount = 4000 });    
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 5, ParentID = 0, Name = "May", Amount = 5000 });
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 6, ParentID = 1, Name = "June", Amount = 6000 });
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 7, ParentID = 1, Name = "July", Amount = 7000 });
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 8, ParentID = 1, Name = "August", Amount = 8000 }); 
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 9, ParentID = 2, Name = "September", Amount = 9000 }); 
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 10, ParentID = 2, Name = "October", Amount = 10000 });
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 11, ParentID = 2, Name = "November", Amount = 11000 });
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 12, ParentID = 10, Name = "December", Amount = 12000 });
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 13, ParentID = 10, Name = "January", Amount = 13000 }); 
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 14, ParentID = 10, Name = "February", Amount = 14000 });
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 15, ParentID = 3, Name = "March", Amount = 15000 });
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 16, ParentID = 3, Name = "April", Amount = 16000 });
objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 17, ParentID = 3, Name = "May", Amount = 17000 });
```

does anyone know how I can write a function that returns a list of an object and all of it's recursive children?

For example if I put in an argument of id = 2 I would like back

```
FlatObject { ID = 2, ParentID = 0, Name = "February", Amount = 2000 });     
FlatObject { ID = 9, ParentID = 2, Name = "September", Amount = 9000 });
FlatObject { ID = 10, ParentID = 2, Name = "October", Amount = 10000 });
FlatObject { ID = 11, ParentID = 2, Name = "November", Amount = 11000 });
FlatObject { ID = 12, ParentID = 10, Name = "December", Amount = 12000 });
FlatObject { ID = 13, ParentID = 10, Name = "January", Amount = 13000 });
FlatObject { ID = 14, ParentID = 10, Name = "February", Amount = 14000 });
```

in a list;

I know how to do this using LINQ if I am getting back just children, but not if I am getting back children and descendants.

Comment: I don't understand how an id of 2 has brought back those results?

Comment: @DeeMac 2 is the parent of 10, 10 is the parent of 13 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ID is always unique, nonzero parent ID's always have a corresponding object in the collection, and all root objects have ParentID zero you can make an extension method that answers whether a certain object is a child or grandchild from an object with a certain ID:

```
public static bool HasAncestor(this FlatObject obj, IEnumerable<FlatObject> objs, int id)
{
    if (obj.ID == id)
       return true;
    if (obj.ParentID == 0)
       return false;
    return objs.Single(o => o.ID == obj.ParentID)  // Get parent
               .HasAncestor(objs, id);             // recurse
}
```

Given that you can also use it the other way, get all objects that have a certain ancestor

```
public static IEnumerable<FlatObject> GetAllChildren(this FlatObject obj, IEnumerable<FlatObject> objs)
{
    return objs.Where(o => o.HasAncestor(objs, obj.ID));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Recursive function as follows in high level,

```
private List<int> GetAllChildren(int parent)
{
    List<T> children = new List<T>();
    PopulateChildren(parent.ID, children);
    return children;
}

private void PopulateChildren(int parent, List<int> children)
{

    //look up immediate childs and pass each child to recursice method and add child to list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your complete solution (Tested). Just add FlatObjectExtention to your solution.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<FlatObject> objects = new List<FlatObject>();

        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 1, ParentID = 0, Name = "January", Amount = 1000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 2, ParentID = 0, Name = "February", Amount = 2000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 3, ParentID = 0, Name = "March", Amount = 3000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 4, ParentID = 0, Name = "April", Amount = 4000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 5, ParentID = 0, Name = "May", Amount = 5000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 6, ParentID = 1, Name = "June", Amount = 6000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 7, ParentID = 1, Name = "July", Amount = 7000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 8, ParentID = 1, Name = "August", Amount = 8000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 9, ParentID = 2, Name = "September", Amount = 9000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 10, ParentID = 2, Name = "October", Amount = 10000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 11, ParentID = 2, Name = "November", Amount = 11000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 12, ParentID = 10, Name = "December", Amount = 12000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 13, ParentID = 10, Name = "January", Amount = 13000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 14, ParentID = 10, Name = "February", Amount = 14000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 15, ParentID = 3, Name = "March", Amount = 15000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 16, ParentID = 3, Name = "April", Amount = 16000 });
        objects.Add(new FlatObject { ID = 17, ParentID = 3, Name = "May", Amount = 17000 });

        objects.First(x=>x.ID==2).GetAllChildren(objects).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class FlatObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("ID={0} ParentID={1} Name={2} Amount={3} ", ID, ParentID, Name, Amount);
    }
}

public static class FlatObjectExtention
{
    public static IList<FlatObject> GetAllChildren(this FlatObject flatObject, IList<FlatObject> allItems)
    {
        var allChildren = new List<FlatObject>();
        var children = allItems.Where(x => x.ParentID == flatObject.ID).ToList();
        allChildren.AddRange(children);

        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            allChildren.AddRange(child.GetAllChildren(allItems));
        }
        return allChildren;
    }
}
```

Comment: Additionally you had better know the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), which is a design pattern for such scenarios.